# dart/flutter - Class 'Datum' has no instance method '[]'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a podo class which takes data from API.
That is working fine. In the dropdown field I am using the value of id and showing the name.

Example Json data from api response is like below:

```
{"jsonapi":{"version":"1.0"},"data":[{"type":"testkit","id":"1","attributes":{"active":true,"testType":"type1","code":"T101","name":"TestName1","infos":{},}},{"type":"testkit","id":"2","attributes":{"active":true,"testType":"type2","code":"T102","name":"TestName2","productId":null,"infos":{}}}]}
```

for snapshot:

```
child: FutureBuilder(
       future: _testkit,
       builder: (context,
       AsyncSnapshot<TestkitList> snapshot) {
```

the drowdownFieldWidget code is like below:

```
DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
hint:Text("Select Testkit Name"),
value: _selectedTestkit,
                onChanged: (newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                    _selectedTestkit = newValue;
_selectedTestType = getTestType()// this I am trying to get the value of test type, but not working.

                    });
                },
                validator: (value) => value ==
                        null
                    ? 'Please select the Testkit'
                    : null,
                items: (snapshot.data.data)
                    .map((item) =>
                        DropdownMenuItem<
                            String>(
                            child: Text(
                            item.attributes.name
                                        .length >
                                    30
                                ? item
                                    .attributes
                                    .name
                                    .substring(
                                        0, 30)
                                : item
                                    .attributes
                                    .name,
                            ),
                            value: item.id,
                        ))
                    .toList(),
                );
            }
        }
        }),
)),
```

Now In addition to id for selected item, I also need to access the value of `testType` under `attributes`

I tried to access the value by creating a function `getTestType()` like below:

```
getTestType() async {    

    final List testkits = await responsetestkit.then((value) => value.data);
    print("below line is printed in function getTestType");
    print(testkits.runtimeType);
    
    print(testkits);
    var testtype =
        testkits.firstWhere((testkit) => testkit["id"] == _selectedTestkit);  

    print(testtype);
    
  }
```

this function is returning the error - `Class 'Datum' has no instance method '[]'.`

Please let me know if any further information needed.

update: contents of Podo file:

```
import 'dart:convert';

TestkitList testkitListFromMap(String str) => TestkitList.fromMap(json.decode(str));

String testkitListToMap(TestkitList data) => json.encode(data.toMap());

class TestkitList {
    TestkitList({
        this.jsonapi,
        this.data,
    });

    Jsonapi jsonapi;
    List<Datum> data;

    factory TestkitList.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => TestkitList(
        jsonapi: json["jsonapi"] == null ? null : Jsonapi.fromMap(json["jsonapi"]),
        data: json["data"] == null ? null : List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromMap(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "jsonapi": jsonapi == null ? null : jsonapi.toMap(),
        "data": data == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toMap())),
    };
}

class Datum {
    Datum({
        this.type,
        this.id,
        this.attributes,
    });

    String type;
    String id;
    Attributes attributes;

    factory Datum.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        type: json["type"] == null ? null : json["type"],
        id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
        attributes: json["attributes"] == null ? null : Attributes.fromMap(json["attributes"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "type": type == null ? null : type,
        "id": id == null ? null : id,
        "attributes": attributes == null ? null : attributes.toMap(),
    };
}

class Attributes {
    Attributes({
        this.active,
        this.testType,
        this.code,
        this.name,        
        this.infos,
        
    });

    bool active;
    String testType;
```

Comment: Can you print `testkits` value?

Comment: yes. I can print testkit value id as well as can show the testkit name in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you `getTestType` method is marked as `async`, then this only returns a `Future` and needs `then` or `await` to get the value:

```dart
onChanged: (newValue) async {
  _selectedTestkit = newValue; 
  _selectedTestType = await getTestType();
  setState(() {});
},
```

Second, the `getTestType` method does not returns any value. Fix adding return value:

```dart
getTestType() async {    
  final List testkits = await responsetestkit.then((value) => value.data);
  print("below line is printed in function getTestType");
  print(testkits.runtimeType);
  
  print(testkits);
  var testtype =
      testkits.firstWhere((testkit) => testkit["id"] == _selectedTestkit);  

  print(testtype);
  return testtype;
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error. full error is like this:`Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Datum' has no instance method '[]'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Datum'
Tried calling: []("id"))`

Comment: You have a class named `Datum` on you project?

Comment: The testkits has a List of Datum instances? If yes, can you add to your post the definition for this class?

Comment: yes the podo file testkitlist contains Testkitlist class and datum class.

Comment: Please update your post adding the `Testkitlist` and `Datum` class deffinition

Comment: Added. please check.

Comment: Ok, change `var testtype =
      testkits.firstWhere((testkit) => testkit["id"] == _selectedTestkit);` to `var testtype =
      testkits.firstWhere((testkit) => testkit.id == _selectedTestkit);` If not works, print the value and type of `testkits`.

Comment: Now it is not showing the exception error - but it is still not fetching the value. like runtime type of testkit is `List<Datum>` and when I print in function getTestType() - I am getting multiple times - `Instance of 'Datum', Instance of 'Datum', Instance of 'Datum'`
same in dropdwon - but just once - 'Instance of 'Datum''`

Comment: Now, change the `return testtype;` to `return testtype.type;` in `getTestType`.

Comment: I think you are a dart/flutter master. it worked. actually for my purpose I needed `testtype.attributes.testtype` that worked as well. Thank you so much.